How do I get Ubuntu to open a USB SD card drive in Files?
I have been using the given USB-C dongle type drive and the 32 GB microSD card for a couple years with no issue. Plug device in, the Files app sees it, and you open it like any folder on any graphical OS I've ever used. Then I updated today using the Software Updater, and now it doesn't work. The light goes on, but nothing happens. The Disks app can see it and tell it's a 32 GB drive. It even gives me the option of reformatting it, but I can't open it in Files and see the files, or put files on it. I'm not interested in using it from the terminal.

You've not provided any Ubuntu product or release details; you do mention GUI so you're probably talking about a Desktop release, but being specific allows us to better understand and thus help.  Is this an installed or live system, you've not mentioned any specific apps (what you installed controls defaults & you've not told us what that was yet) etc..

if you open the file manager app and then click on "Computer" in the left column, your newly inserted SD card should appear there, at which point you can click on it to open it in the right panel. i suspect this isn't exactly the behavior you are after (you want file manager to open automatically and showing the SD card contents), but at least it gets you easy access for the moment.
the likely reason it is not opening automatically is that Linux has decided that the SD card is not "removable media". since this occurred after an update, it could well be a bug that (hopefully) will be noticed and fixed with another update soon.
